# angular default route of default route

Tags: angular, router

With @angular/router 7.2.5, when redirecting to a default route that itself has a default route, the nested default route is not hit.

In other words, with this route configuration:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/hello', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'hello', component: HelloComponent, children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'child', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'child', component: ChildComponent }
]}
```

The route `/hello` will redirect to `/hello/child` as expected, but the route `/` will redirect to `/hello` instead of  `/hello/child`. What am I missing?

This issue is demonstrated on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3h3gt9

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `/` in the parent redirect route.  The `redirectTo:` has to match a path in your router.  It's trying to match `/hello` which you do not have.

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'hello', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'hello', component: HelloComponent, children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'child', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'child', component: ChildComponent }
]}
```